# Get all indexes after 2nd index from array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm pretty new to NodeJS and I'm trying to get all indexes after 2nd index from an array.

My Code as below:

```
module.exports.run = async(client,message,args) => {
    let user = args[0];
    let song = args[1];
    let msg = args[2];
    var data = {
        user:args[0],
        song:args[1],
        msg:msg,
        requestType: 'request'
    };
```

I want to get all indexes after 2nd index, from args array. How can I achieve that? Thanks.

Edit: Command will be executed like: `!request user song multiple word message

Comment: Kindly post your desired output too so it'll be easy to answer.

Comment: @SyedKashanAli There you go, i think that is the thing you wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `slice` method:

```js
let args = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let newArgs = args.slice(3);
console.log(newArgs); // prints [4, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this has returned Array when I tried to get all of it, since I won't be able to know how many words were there.

Comment: @BerkayGunduz You can get number of `args` item by: `args.length`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `splice` method too:

```js
let args = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let newArgs = args.splice(0,2);
console.log("How many removed = ", JSON.stringify(newArgs));
console.log("What is remaining = ", JSON.stringify(args) , "length= ", args.length);
```

**Please Note:-** `splice` will alter your actual array.